# combo box extender ajax tool kit

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a filter on the page and i am using 5 combo boxes. The data in the combo box is getting filled properly. However when i select the drop down of combo box and select any item from the list. I get this error..

"Invalid Argument"

and the debugger points to style.width = bestWidth + 'px'

i tried searching everywhere but no common errors.

Comment: can you show us the code where you have this line  "style.width = bestWidth + 'px'"

Comment: what is value of `bestWidth`?  Have you tried to set width by hard-coding the value, like `style.width=100px;`?

Comment: the code is inbuilt..!! it comes in a dynamically created file of script resource.

Comment: the value of best width is -2. I cannot hard code it because it is created dynamically. I tried giving style.width from the propert of combo box where I am using it but even that dint help

Comment: the function which shows _getOptionsListWidth:function()

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue, reported here: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=22848

and you can read more about it here: http://lionsden.co.il/codeden/?p=285

Answer (score 0):

As i know [Style.Width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.style.width.aspx) takes an [Unit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40b0wfkw.aspx) as an value so i am not sure what bestwidth +'px' is doing there but if you want it to be in pixel then have it like this:

```
style.width = new Unit(Convert.ToDouble(bestwidth), UnitType.Pixel);
```

Comment: i cannot change this.. it is created dynamically. in a script resource file

Comment: Which is created dynamically the code containing "style.Width" or "bestwidth" ??

Comment: style.width = bestWidth + 'px'  this entire line gets highlighted with yellow the moment i select any thing from my combo box and click on go..!!

Comment: style.width = bestWidth + 'px' this entire line is seen in a dynamic page of scriptresource under the function of _getOptionsListWidth:function()